# Can haproxy be used as a browser proxy?

Tags: centos, redhat, haproxy

Can haproxy be used as a browser proxy?
In other words I want the `frontend` to be the internal network and the `backend` to be the Internet.

Comment: You can find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605766/use-haproxy-as-an-reverse-proxy-with-an-application-behind-internet-proxy

Comment: That is not quite what I need. I just need haproxy to forward all the requests of a certain front end to whatever the URL in the http request.

Comment: I think "Squid Proxy" is what you are looking for :)